# xpath Located <p> but return None

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, python-3.6

I'm using selenium.webdriver chrome to crawl data from my website, and want to get the location from visitors. 
I have successfully located the `<p>` label which contains 'location', but it return None.

Need help here. Many Thanks

I have tried `.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')` and `.remove_space(location).strip()` but it returns  `NoneType` object has no attribute 'replace'

my python code is below

```
  location=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="module contact_module expanded"]//p[1]').get_attribute('text')
    print(location)
    location=location.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
    location=location.remove_space(location).strip()
```

html is here

```
<div class="module contact_module expanded">
        <div class="module-header">
          <ul class="actions">
            <li><a href="#" class="toggle_module" title="Expand / Collapse Section"><i class="icon-collapse-alt" data-expand="icon-expand-alt" data-collapse="icon-collapse-alt"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
          <h2>Contact <span><a href="#" class="update-module">Edit</a></span></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="module-content contact-module">


          <h4>Email / Phone / Social</h4>
          <ul class="contact-list unstyled">

            <li class="contact-email">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <a href="df@hotmail.com" target="_blank">df@hotmail.com</a>
            </li>








            <li class="contact-phone empty_row"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (blank)</li>







          </ul>




            <h4>Location</h4>
            <p>Boondall, Queensland, Australia</p>



            <h4>Timezone</h4>
            <p>Australia/Brisbane</p>

        </div>
      </div>
```

I expected 'Boondall, Queensland, Australia' but the actual output is None

Comment: Your example html doesn't have a div that matches `/div[@class="module contact_module expanded"]`

Comment: My mistake.  Just edited my example. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, given your html, `//p[1]/text()` should get you there.

Comment: I'v tried /text() but it will turns out "no such element."  I guess it doesn't recognize the text from <p> as an attribute.  Maybe this reason also explains why .get_attribute('text') doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 location=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="module contact_module expanded"]//p[1]').text
```